# Hover style after open another page

Tags: mousehover

I have mousehover style for div that has a href inside.
When click it open new browser tab. When I go back to original page, hover style still there, unless I move mouse outside the div.
How I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an onclick event on the selected element

You select the div by using document.getElementById then put an `onclick` event on it and remove the `attribute` in this case the `hover class`

```js
   var box = document.getElementById('hover');

   
   box.onclick = function(){
     box.removeAttribute("class")
    }
```

```css
.test:hover {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='hover' class="test"> 
   <a href="google.com" target="_blank">blah</a> 
   </div>
```

Comment: Problem is moving to another page and come back.

Comment: How do you mean? You said you open the link in a new tab, so the old one still remains. If you open in the same tab, the style will ofcourse reset so the hover will still be there.

Comment: yes, I open new tab. When come back to old tab, hover style still there